# Why android Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE result code is always 0 (CANCELLED)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I have an app where the user can have a profile picture and they can also submit photo to contribute to some items information. 
But I can't figured out why my camera intent always return with a "cancelled" result code.

I create the intent via a chooser intent where they can choose between their photo application and it works fine if they pick an image from a gallery or whatever. I have a class PhotoTaker with this function that is call on photo fab button click:

```
public void startTakingSinglePhoto(View view) {
    if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), PERMS)) {
        isAskPermissionOnTakingSinglePhoto = true;
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getResources().getString(R.string.popup_title_permission_files_access), RC_TAKE_PHOTO, PERMS);
        return;
    }

    Intent i = getCameraIntent();

    startActivityForResult(i, RC_TAKE_PHOTO);
}
```

Here is `getCameraIntent`:

```
private Intent getCameraIntent() {

    Intent cameraIntent= new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //Create the local file where will be store camera picture
    File photoFile;
    photoFile = createImageFile();
    if (photoFile != null) {
       Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITIES, photoFile);
       cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    }else{
       Log.e("=>", "photo file is null");
    }
    return cameraIntent;
}
```

And here is `createImageFile`:

```
private File createImageFile() {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "RideMonPark_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

I then have a class `GalleryActivity` which is used to create a gallery with all the images the users submits. It extends `PhotoTaker` which has all the above code.

Here's `onActivityResult` in `GalleryActivity`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.w("=>", "gallery activity result : " + requestCode + " : " + resultCode);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_TAKE_PHOTO:
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.sending_picture), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w("=>", "intent : " + data);
                if(data == null || data.getData() == null){
                    //FROM CAMERA add current path file uri
                    Log.w("=>", "from camera : " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    addPhotoInGallery(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                }else{
                    //From gallery, add File Uri
                    Log.w("=>", "from gallery : " + data.getData().toString());
                    addPhotoInGallery(data.getData().toString());
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I never have the chance to enter `onActivityResult` since the first log shows a result code of 0 with camera app.

I don't have enough bandwidth to download another AVD so I have only tested on my Honor8 and the Virtual Google Pixel 2.

I have read a lot that it's not so much of a good idea to rely on the user camera app since almost every phone has their own different camera app. Should I make my own? I'm the only developer on this app and I'm short on time. I have thought that making a camera for the app is not worth it, but if it's the only solution to get it work on all devices, I will do it...

Edit : 
Here is my provider tag in manifest :

```
  <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.name.example"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And my file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.name.example/files/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: `Intent i = getPickImageChooserIntent();` replace by `Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` and try again. Why dit you post such complicated code to build up your picker intent?

Comment: This way i get RESULT_OK but cannot get access to full-size picture. Only low res bitmap from the picture. If i want to access the full size picture from camera i need to store it in a file. So the problem is when i try store the full-size picture...
And i build picker intent long time ago so it must be from different response found on internet. But he was working since now.
Is there a simple way to find all ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent in the phone ?

Comment: `This way i cannot get access to full-size picture.` Indeed i oversaw that. Sorry.  But then you could add your FileProvider code there in a few lines. You should not bother us with all that allIntents code. Please try.

Comment: `Is there a simple way to find all ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent in the phone ?` That looks to me a question for another thread.  And i do not know why you wanno know.

Comment: `have read a lot that it's not so much of a good idea to rely on the user camera app since almost every phone has their own different camera app. Should I make my own?` Never read that. Dont write your own. If the user is not satisfied other camera apps from playstore can be installed.

Comment: I have remove useless code since the problem come from only my camera intent. Sorry for that.
`Never read that. Dont write your own. If the user is not satisfied other camera apps from playstore can be installed`. Sorry if unclear, i have try to find a solution to my problem before posting this and i ran across a lot of post regarding other issues from using constructors default camera app or depending on playstore camera app since for exemple they not always return a URI in `getData()`.

Comment: `Sorry. But then you could add your FileProvider code there in a few lines.` I already use FileProvider as you saw when i create my camera intent, the file is created and i get a URI like :  `content://com.package.app/timestamp.jpg` but again camera intent result code is 0.

Comment: `File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` The Pictures directory is not normally found in getExternalFilesDir(). So better check if it exists and if not create it. `if ( !storageDir.exists()) if ( !storageDir.mkdirs()) { Toast ( could not create directory);  return null;}`.

Comment: `i get a URI like : content://com.package.app/timestamp.jpg` ??? Where do you get such an uri? It looks invalid. Show providertag in manifest and your paths.xml file.

Comment: `Log.e("=>", "photo file is null");` Your code is not robust as even if you print that log you will start the camera. You can do better.

Comment: `Where do you get such an uri?` post edited. 
I have add the storageDir check thank you for that. But my file is still not created. I have change `photoFile != null` to `photoFile.exists()` and it doesn't exist. Even with the storageDir mkdirs.

Comment: `It seems like my file from createImageFile is not created. –` Very good. You should not create the file already there.(there is nothing in that code that would create a file).  The file will be created by the camera app. Imagine you create an empty file there (filesize==0) and the user cancels picture taking. You would be left with an empty file.

Comment: `android:authorities="com.name.example"` Better change to `android:authorities="com.name.example.provider"` But... we cannot check yet if you do all ok as we cannot see what would be 'AUTHORITIES'. Please put in your code. (And add .provider there too). It should be the same.

Comment: `You would be left with an empty file` i just check in my File and as you say, i have some 0mb file. How can i save the full size image if i'm not giving the camera app an existing URI with `putExtra(EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)` ? 
All this code for creating file for the camera app came from the android docs : [Android Take Photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath)

Comment: Of course you do all ok. And you should use putExtra(EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri) as you do now. The function name createImageFile() is misleading as it does not create a file but only gives you a File object which is good. Remove the files with size 0. They are from earlier experiments i think. They will not come again...

Comment: `All this code for creating file for the camera app came from the android docs : Android Take Photo –` No. As the createImageFile() in the example creates a file already which is terrible. But your createImageFile() does not and that is fine.

Comment: Ok so if i understand the example in the official doc is terrible ? I'm still a junior dev so i was thinking following the docs would'nt cause me issue... 
Yes i have modified a little bit because i wasn't fine with the `createTempFile()` from the doc.
So i have now an other error since i have add `.provider` at the end of my provider tag in manifest. Should i have .provider in my `AUTHORITIES` constant and in my file_path also or not ?

Comment: Show how you defined `AUTHORITIES` Put the define in your code above. (I asked that before). And it should be the same as in the manifest file.

Comment: `Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITIES, photoFile);` Log.d(TAG, "AUTHORITIES: " + AUTHORITIES); Log.d(TAG, "photoFile: " + photoFile.getAbsolutePath()); Log.d(TAG, "photoURI: " + photoURI.toString()); Put all in your code and tell us what is logged please.

Comment: `And it should be the same as in the manifest file` So i got it working, only my `file_path` doesn't include the `.provider` at the end. 
The error was coming from not creating storageDir and also that i have put `/` in my timestamp file name... I'm so stupid. 
Thanks a lot for your help and your time blackaaps ! Since you didn't post an answer but only comment how can i value your help ?

Comment: `also that i have put / in my timestamp file name..` I should have seen that. I'm ashamed.

Comment: `I'm ashamed` Me too for making such a dumb mistake... I have a lot of `Date.format` in my app so i decide to define a constant for it a few days ago and didn't realize i was using it for a file name until now.. Sorry for the loose of time.